# Cannot recreate curl request

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to acquire phone numbers from https://lajumate.ro/ajax/phone-number ([example product page](https://lajumate.ro/volkswagen-passat-3834372.html))

The page requires a POST mechanism with certain cookies and data. An example of the CURL request is shown below:

```
curl 'https://lajumate.ro/ajax/phone-number'  -H 'Cookie:  XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IkVqUEwrZjU2UDJOaFB3NDl6b0xhTFE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiemJnTCt3S0UxTjUwVjVTQk0xUzlRSVpNZGVPM0dIVHBcL1JlYTVabmcxelFPNG5ZZ1d4NGYxbmpnRTAxeVRSaWRcLzZTUVhRVzlNcmtyOHJvcWFOdlE3UT09IiwibWFjIjoiYmUzOGNkNDlkMjMyNzY3YTQxNzE0ZWEwNmJhMDExZWUzODdmZmU5MmZmMTEwODk1ZTE3ZjYxNTkxZjYyNzFkOCJ9; ljs= eyJpdiI6ImdYR28xcnZvSXFiNHpSekVyeHJOQVE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiSnJtTlBRMmRJY1ZqNUtxWXdPREdlYnptc3pKWGRmZ1ppdjdCc0lcL040NzlDbytTcWNZb1Bwa0kyejlKM3NmNGZ0dDMwcFNhaXZ6WHlWSExFaHlNYnFnPT0iLCJtYWMiOiI4ZWY2MzRiNTY5Mjc3M2FmYjllNDJiODEyYWRmNzUxNjViYWM0OTIyZjQ3OTRjODhiMjM3N2NlNTJjYWJiNTRiIn0;'  --data '_token=lT8dwMv5vqGrnh0drb6pW7sreYjguJn5qaCXZIck&ad_id=3834372' --compressed
```

This works (note that the cookies & tokens expire). So I've created a spider to recreate this request. Code is shown below:

```
    req = FormRequest(
        'https://lajumate.ro/ajax/phone-number', 
        callback=self.parse_phone, 
        formdata={'ad_id':re.sub(r".+?(\d+)\.html",r"\1",response.url),'_token':response.xpath('//input[@name="_token"]/@value').extract()[0]}, 
        headers={'Cookie':'ljs='+ljs+';XSRF-TOKEN='+XSRF},
        dont_filter=True
        )
```

ljs and XSRF are fetched from the response cookies.

I'm using two debug loggers to check the request:

```
    self.logger.debug('Request headers: %s', dict(req.headers))
    self.logger.debug('Request body: %s', req.body)
```

Resulting in:

> 2017-01-04 11:44:41 [lajumate-sellers] DEBUG: Request headers:
> {'Cookie':
> ['ljs=eyJpdiI6IlBTU05tWlV0NW1DZGJaZk5nemEzTUE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiY3JDNFR2clpkMGVaNHVqODZFT2NvTmFRb1BKRmZCS0pCRndwd0xNNXVzV2M1WUNCUm5MWXFnbEU5RGZkQnVRNHFNMFp5S0E4TllkZXVtNk5cL3JSU1FBPT0iLCJtYWMiOiJhOWRhYmJmODg1NzcwOTRhNzQ5ZTlhNDg4OTEzZWNiNDc5NDhlNzZmMmQ3MDliYjM0ODlkZDAwOTYzN2NkNTkzIn0%3D;XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6ImNHNzZhbVViNWxTUm16bmg5amF0SFE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiWGRPMWFjVFBPTFNYWkxrNjI2THJIYU1KeStLcTg4Z3FFRkFqOWJjMDdHNUJKNXFuY2pKVXkxTVpuT1ExNXpSZWZHM1FPMzRjSTY0R3lSVndJME1GMFE9PSIsIm1hYyI6ImQwYThlMGQzYzA3NjA3YmE2ZTAwYjA0NjRiNzRjNTY4NGVlNjEwZjUxMzFiMWE0OGI3Nzk5YWVlNmVkODllNGEifQ%3D%3D'],
> 'Content-Type': ['application/x-www-form-urlencoded']}
>
> 2017-01-04 11:44:41 [lajumate-sellers] DEBUG: Request body:
> _token=VtCrPpqMwpcO1FRCZ12pnYmXj7Bv14B8o4aRcZyA&ad_id=3576651

This all looks like it should be. But when the spider tries to load the page, it redirects the request with a 302 status code.

However, when I copy paste the debug data into the curl command or hurl.it I'm able to acquire the data.

Any suggestions how to tackle this problem?

Comment: `ljs= ey` - Not sure if that's a type-o.. But cookies rarely start off with a space. Also 302 isn't necessarily a bad thing... It might just mean that you need to follow the redirect.

Comment: The curl request works. It is the scrapy request that fails. And I know the 302 is not a bad thing for all cases but it is in mine, since it leads me away from the phone number.